# How does ngSwitch work in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to use ngSwitch as [in this example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgSwitch-directive.html)
but I get an error:

[image]

My Component:

```
  template: `
    <div layout="column" layout-align="center center">   
   <div [ng-switch]="value">
       <div *ng-switch-when="'init'">
     <button md-raised-button class="md-raised md-primary">User</button>
     <button md-raised-button class="md-raised md-primary">Non user</button>

     </div>
  <div *ng-switch-when="0">Second template</div>
  <div *ng-switch-when="1">Third Template</div>
</div>
  </div>`,
    directives: [NgSwitch, NgSwitchWhen, NgSwitchDefault]
 })
```

[My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yNjEkzWoLGbtu09s0eHn?p=preview)  - wizard.ts

What did I miss? Thank you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**update**

See https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

**original**

Templates are case sensitive (since beta.47 AFAIR). Directive (attribute) selectors were changed to camel case. For example from `ng-switch` to `ngSwitch`.

Tag names still use dashes for compatibility with web components. For example `<router-link>`, `<ng-content>`.

More details to `ngSwitchCase`

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitchCase-directive.html

> ```
> <container-element [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
>   <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</some-element>
> </container-element>
> ```

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

> ```
> <container-element [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
>   <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</some-element>
>   <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_2">...</some-element>
>   <some-other-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">...</some-other-element>
>   <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">
>     <!-- use a ng-container to group multiple root nodes -->
>     <inner-element></inner-element>
>     <inner-other-element></inner-other-element>
>   </ng-container>
>   <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
> </container-element>
> ```

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitchDefault-directive.html

> ```
> <container-element [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
>   <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</some-element>
>   <some-other-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-other-element>
> </container-element>
> ```

Comment: Instead of downvoting you could give a hint what you think is wrong so I can fix it.

Answer (score 37):

***Old way***

---

***[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QSXr7U3g6T1081w9SB7X?p=preview)***. *you can check browser's console*

changed **ng-switch** to ***ngSwitch***
changed **ng-switch-when** to ***ngSwitchWhen***

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="center center">

       <div [ngSwitch]="value">
      <div *ngSwitchWhen="'init'">
         <button md-raised-button class="md-raised md-primary">User</button>
         <button md-raised-button class="md-raised md-primary">Non user</button>

      </div>
      <div *ngSwitchWhen="0">Second template</div>
      <div *ngSwitchWhen="1">Third Template</div>
    </div>
 </div>
   <button md-fab
 class="md-fab wizard_button--next"
  aria-label="about"
  (click)="onNext()">
<i class="material-icons" md-icon="">play_arrow</i>
 </button>
```

---

***New Way***

***ANGULAR.2.0.0*** OR ***Final Relase***

---

**UPDATE** : How to Use **ngSwitch** in **Angular2.0.0** or **final release** ???

Please note things have changed in final release so if you are using final release please go through below simple example.

**Simple DEMO : http://plnkr.co/edit/IXmUm2Th5QGIRmTFBtQG?p=preview**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <button (click)="value=1">select - 1</button>
  <button (click)="value=2">select - 2</button>
  <button (click)="value=3">select - 3</button>
  <h5>You selected : {{value}}</h5>

  <hr>
  <div [ngSwitch]="value">

     <div *ngSwitchCase="1">1. Template - <b>{{value}}</b> </div>
     <div *ngSwitchCase="2">2. Template - <b>{{value}}</b> </div>
     <div *ngSwitchCase="3">3. Template - <b>{{value}}</b> </div>
     <div *ngSwitchDefault>Default Template</div>

  </div>
  `,

})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used old examples

Comment: ngSwitchWhen has become ngSwitchCase. Please update the Answer

Comment: @vcs. Updated answer to final release.

Answer (score 13):

Three things to keep in mind `ngSwitch`, `ngSwitchCase` and `ngSwitchDefault`.

1. **ngSwitch** - set the `property value` of `model`. For example - `viewMode`, which is a property in your component.
2. **ngSwitchCase** - Defines what to render when the `value` of the `property` defined in `ngSwitchChanges`.  For ex. when `viewMode = 'map'`
3. **ngSwitchDefault** - Defines what to render if the `value` doesn't match.  For ex. when `viewMode=undefined`.  The default will be `rendered`.

Another **important point** is that we need to set the `[ngSwitchCase]` within a `<template></template>` *HTML element* otherwise it will not work.  `Angular`will automatically convert it into a `<div>` tag.

```js
    <div [ngSwitch]="'viewMode'">
      <template [ngSwitchCase]="'map'" ngSwitchDefault> 
         Map View Content...   
       </template>      
       <template [ngSwitchCase]="'list'"> 
          List View Content...
      </template>
    </div>
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Upvote for using a string example. Almost every time keep forgetting the single quotes.

Answer (score 5):

There is also *ngSwitchDefault which I didn't see in documentation over on site.  Just like the name implies it will default to this if it doesn't meet the other cases.

This is mainly a heads up if someone runs into this.