# Display Html element according to a template variable

Tags: angular, angular-template-variable

An HTML template of my application has 3 div
Each of these divs has a specific template variable.
Let’s assume the following code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div #variable1>Some content 1</div>
  <div #variable2>Some content 2</div>
  <div #variable3>Some content 3</div>
</div>
```

I would like to have a function in the model that works on the basis of a switch. Depending on the variable, I could display the contents of the desired div element.
The mechanism of the function might look like this:

```
  displaySpecificDiv(element: HTMLElement) {
    switch (element) {
      case 'variable1':
      // display div 1
      case 'variable2':
      // display div 2
      // And so on...
    }
  }
```

Then I could call this function through a menu that would allow me to display divs like this:

```
   <ul class="menu">
    <li
        (click)="displaySpecificDiv(variable1)"
        <span>item 1</span>
    </li>
    <li
      (click)="displaySpecificDiv(variable2)"
      <span>item 2</span>
    </li>
    <li
      (click)="displaySpecificDiv(variable3)"
      <span>item 3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: this is more typically done in angular via routing with child routes and the parent route containing the menu

Comment: also: [How does ngSwitch work in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777062/how-does-ngswitch-work-in-angular2)

Comment: Yes, the goal is to know if I can do without the <router-outlet></router-outlet> directive

Comment: then use *ngIf or ngSwitch, and in the method toggle variable value, see the linked question

Comment: I’m doing it now, thanks